# javascript two tables export to csv but aligned one next to the other

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv

In `javascript` I have three tables in three separate `strings` and I want to export them to one `csv-string` but aligned one next to the other. now I'm using this -

```
csvString = csvString1 + '\n' + csvString2 + '\n' + csvString3;
```

I know That `'\n'` is breaking the line. how can I export to excel the three table aligned?? thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the language of the Excel program. Some need , and some need ; in stead of \n

Comment: Thanks. not working..